# sql IN statement to be always true

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following sql query

```
select * from tblArea where AreaDescription in ('Processing1','Geology 66','Site Infrastructure')
```

currently it shows the records where AreaDescription in ('Processing1','Geology 66','Site Infrastructure')

but i need to pass value to in query which will be always true and show all the records.i know  that i can use where clause

```
where 1=1
```

but here i need to use the in statement.is it possible?

Comment: Add `or 1=1` to the end of the query and you'll get all the records from the table.

Comment: yes it's working.but isn't there any other way to do this with out modifying the current query.i mean achieve this just by passing a parameter to the query?

Comment: the reason behind is at the moment i can not modify production queries only allowed to modify the parameters passing to the query

Comment: And how is that 'parameter' being passed? as a comma separated list?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't understand why you need it and why you don't want to add `where 1=1` or omit the `WHERE`, but you could do it this way:

```
select * from tblArea 
where AreaDescription in 
(AreaDescription,'Processing1','Geology 66','Site Infrastructure')
```

Test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e15d/1/0

Comment: Doesn't neccessarily return all rows though. Is equivalent to `WHERE AreaDescription IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

if you want your query to be always `true`,

- remove the where clause
- or add `OR 1=1`

Comment: You didn't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

`select * from tblArea where AreaDescription in (select AreaDescription from tblArea)`